# Get data from firebase with multiple values

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

[image: this is my firebase database]

I want to get all route_number(example:"rt45") which contains stops(example:"hapur chungi").

i need a firebase query in java which returns all routenumber which have **"hapur chungi"** and **"lal kaun"** as their stops
The stops names are variable and user may need result for **"hapur chungi"** and **"mohan nagar"** as their stops

**Code after getting the first solution** i got the correct output but for that i have to click  the button twice to load the data.
[the code i have used after reporting my initial problem but now i have to click button twice to get output](https://shrib.com/#CarpetPython2Gw1VPD)

Comment: Sounds like you're looking to use a Firebase query, which allows you to select nodes that have specific child values. The main problem with that is that it doesn't scale well, since the node *name* is dynamic in your scenario. For on why this is, and how to model this data to allow the use-case, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: i found it very useful but a problem arises now that i have to click the button twice in order to retrieve data, when i click the button once it doesnot show any data but when i click it again it shows accurate output

Comment: i have added the code which i used after Frank_van provided the solution

Comment: That sounds like a related, follow-up problem. I recommend opening a new question and showing the [minimal, complete/standalone code + JSON that anyone of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).